# Ansible linefile module's attribute line is not adding environmental variable on server

Tags: automation, ansible

Hi I am having a task which is as follows

```
   - name: Replace log directory in configuration
      lineinfile:
        path: $HOME/amsible_test/test.txt
        regexp: '^dataDir='
        line: 'dataDir=$HOME/.zookeeper_log'
```

it's running fine , But issue is that this is writing line as `dataDir=$HOME/.zookeeper_log`

but as per my understanding it should parse `$HOME` as `/home/username` as per ubuntu 16.04 .It should write `dataDir=/home/username/.zookeeper.log` but not doing as expected.

any suggestion what i am doing wrong . I tried many alternate for string parsing purpose but no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an arbitrary remote user's home directory in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343215/how-to-get-an-arbitrary-remote-users-home-directory-in-ansible)

Comment: @nwinkler not found my solution there

Comment: Not even this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43778560/1228454

Comment: @nwinkler My ansible version is ansible 2.7.2 .this syntax is also not working for me

Comment: Ansible does *not* do shell variable substitution in module's arguments. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this worked for me ..

```
- name: test connection
  shell: echo $HOME
  register: user_home

- name: Replace log directory in configuration

  lineinfile:
    path: $HOME/amsible_test/test.txt
    regexp: '^dataDir='
    line: 'dataDir={{user_home.stdout}}/.zookeeper_log'
```

Comment: Its also possible do something like this: `line: 'dataDir={{ lookup('env','HOME') }}/.zookeeper_log'`... Doing that, you wont need the first shell task.

Comment: The lookup call is done on the control machine, not on the remote machine, that‘s why you can‘t use lookup in this case...

Comment: Agree with @nwinkler